# Do kernel and kernel modules have their own task_struct?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I know that in user space, both processes and threads have corresponding task_structs.

I've also found information that kthreads have their own task_structs, with mm_struct=NULL.

But what I'm curious about is, do kernel and modules loaded via insmod/modprobe into the kernel also have their own task_structs?

I'm asking this because I've been using`current->nsproxy->mnt_ns`
in my own kernel module, but I'm not sure who current represents when executing the code in kernel module. Does it refer to a specific process, or does it point to the kernel itself?

I do that since I want to iterate all current mountpoints through access `mnt_list` in mount_namespace in my own kernel module

And I found the implement like the function `is_local_mountpoint` in `fs/namespace.c` https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namespace.c#L763

This has left me quite puzzled, so I'd like to ask for everyone's input.

Comment: kernel modules are also represented as `task_struct`, but to ensure this is a kernel thread you should check if there's no "user-context", i.e. `if (!current->mm) { /* kernel thread */ } else { /* user thread */ } `

Comment: @k1r1t0 Thanks for your reply. So in my kernel module, I use current->nsproxy->mnt_ns to obtain the view of a mount namespace that is identical to the kernel's own namespace, correct?

Comment: yes, you should get initial namespace

Comment: There is no dedicated thread for a Linux kernel module, so there is no specific `task_struct` for it. The module's `module_init` function is executed in the context of the thread which runs `insmod` or `modprobe` for a specific module. The module's `module_exit` function is executed in the context of the thread which runs `rmmod`. Other module functions are executed in corresponding threads too.

Comment: @k1r1t0 *"kernel modules are also represented as task_struct"* - no they are not. You are confusing kernel threds (kthreads) with kernel modules. Two very different things. Kernel modules can create kernel threads.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks so much, so all the functions i written in my module are runnning in kernel space. so I can always get initial namespace by current->nsproxy . Thats like if I use current->nsproxy in my own module_init, the current is represents to the kthread which handling insmod right?

Comment: "the current is represents to the kthread which handling insmod right?" - Unless you are talking about system initialization process, `insmod` is called from the regular user thread. So, `current` references that regular thread.